# XML TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of null

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I am new to scripting and trying to get XML content and attributes

What I have is an api that gives json and converted it into XML:

```
{
    "teams": [
        {
            "id": "3692463",
            "name": "ABC",
            "color": "#f42c2c",
            "avatar": null,
            "members": [
                {
                    "user": {
                        "id": 32288100,
                        "username": "User1",
                        "email": "user1@test.com",
                        "color": "#7c4dff",
                        "profilePicture": null,
                        "initials": "SS",
                        "role": 3,
                        "custom_role": null,
                        "last_active": "1659511910470",
                        "date_joined": "1658927583740",
                        "date_invited": "1658927309161"
                    },
                    "invited_by": {
                        "id": 5952953,
                        "username": "User2",
                        "color": "#02579b",
                        "email": "user2@test.com",
                        "initials": "FC",
                        "profilePicture": null
                    }
                }
```

What I want is to put that into the cells in google spreadsheet.

Thanks to stackoverflow community i have following code:

```
const clickupToken = "pk_***********************"
const clickupReqBody = { "Authorization": clickupToken }
const clickupUrl = "https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/"


function getClickupTeam() {
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(clickupUrl + "team", {
        "method": "GET",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": clickupToken
        }
    }
)

var InputJSON = response;
var output = eval("OBJtoXML("+InputJSON+");")
var content = output; 

var gsheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var mainSheet = gsheet.getSheetByName("MAIN");

const document = XmlService.parse(content); //have the XML service parse the document
Logger.log(document)

const root = document.getRootElement().getChild("members"); //get the root element of the document
Logger.log(root)

const user = root.getChild('user').getChildren();
Logger.log(user)

const list = user.map((username) => [
    username.getAttribute('id').getValue(),
    ...username
      .getChildren()
      .filter((field) =>
       ['username','email', 'role', 'last_active','date_joined','date_invited'].includes(field.getAttribute('id').getValue())
      )
      .map((field) => field.getValue()),
  ]);

var len = list.length;

mainSheet.getRange(2,1,9000,9).clearContent();
mainSheet.getRange(2,1,len,9).setValues(list);

console.log(output);
}

function OBJtoXML(obj) {
  var xml = '';
  for (var prop in obj) {
    xml += obj[prop] instanceof Array ? '' : "<" + prop + ">";
    if (obj[prop] instanceof Array) {
      for (var array in obj[prop]) {
        xml += "<" + prop + ">";
        xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop][array]));
        xml += "</" + prop + ">";
      }
    } else if (typeof obj[prop] == "object") {
      xml += OBJtoXML(new Object(obj[prop]));
    } else {
      xml += obj[prop];
    }
    xml += obj[prop] instanceof Array ? '' : "</" + prop + ">";
  }
  var xml = xml.replace(/<\/?[0-9]{1,}>/g, '');
  return xml
}
```

The above code gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of null at

```
const list = user.map((username) => [
        username.getAttribute('id').getValue(),
```

Did I make a mistake in the script? Is there an easier way to put all the json result into google sheet? Is there an example where I can look at to learn about what I'm trying to do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you want it in xml?  You can use JSON.parse() to turn it back into an object and extract the desired data as you would from any other object.

Comment: user has an attribute id, not username

Comment: @MikeSteelson changed to user still its null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, using JSON.parse

```
function myFunction() {
  const content = `{
   "teams":[
      {
         "id":"3692463",
         "name":"ABC",
         "color":"#f42c2c",
         "avatar":null,
         "members":[
            {
               "user":{
                  "id":32288100,
                  "username":"User1",
                  "email":"user1@test.com",
                  "color":"#7c4dff",
                  "profilePicture":null,
                  "initials":"SS",
                  "role":3,
                  "custom_role":null,
                  "last_active":"1659511910470",
                  "date_joined":"1658927583740",
                  "date_invited":"1658927309161"
               },
               "invited_by":{
                  "id":5952953,
                  "username":"User2",
                  "color":"#02579b",
                  "email":"user2@test.com",
                  "initials":"FC",
                  "profilePicture":null
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}`
  const json = JSON.parse(content)
  let list = []
  json.teams.forEach(t => t.members.forEach(m => list.push(
    [m.user['id'],
    m.user['username'],
    m.user['email'],
    m.user['role'],
    m.user['last_active'],
    m.user['date_joined'],
    m.user['date_invited']]
  )))
  var len = list.length;
  var gsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = gsheet.getSheetByName("MAIN");
  mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, 9000, 7).clearContent();
  mainSheet.getRange(2, 1, len, 7).setValues(list);
}
```